# Where do I store sshfs configuration settings?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, ssh, sshfs

When using `sshfs` several sites recommend using options like:

```
-oauto_cache,reconnect,defer_permissions,negative_vncache,volname=RemoteHome
```

I tried adding these in `~/.ssh/config` under the hostname:

```
Host myserver.net
User myusername
ServerAliveInterval 120
oauto_cache
reconnect
defer_permissions
negative_vncache
volname=RemoteHome
```

The first three work fine but the rest throw errors:

> Bad configuration option: oauto_cache
>   Bad configuration option: reconnect
>   Bad configuration option: defer_permissions
>   Bad configuration option: negative_vncache
>   Bad configuration option: volname

Where can I store these configuration options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can.  The options that **work** in your example above do so because they're ssh options, not sshfs ones.  To work around this you may want to define a function in your ~/.bashrc to invoke sshfs with the parameters you're after.